# Infinite subtraction loop

Tags: optimization

The problem is like this :

Suppose a , b two integers,
We say that (a,b) are infinite if we can repeat the following function infinitely:

```
if a > b :
          a=a-b
          b=2*b
if b > a :
          b=b-a
          a=2*a
```

and 'a' will never be equal to 'b' in any iteration.

Is there a way to test if two integers are infinite without resorting to loops ?

**Example 1:  a=1,b=4**

```
  (1, 4) -> (2, 3) -> (4, 1 -> (3, 2) -> (1, 4) and so on ===> Infinite
```

**Example 2:  a=3,b=5**

```
  (3, 5 -> (6, 2) -> (4, 4) ====> Not Infinite
```

Comment: Why does this have the challenge-response tag?

Comment: Changed the Tag , it's about Optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite your function as follows:

```
a=|a-b|
b=2*min(a,b)
```

Now we can see that if the difference between `a` and `b` is odd, then `a` will be odd in the next round (we just said the difference was odd), and `b` will be even (`2*k` is always even). Therefore the difference will be odd in the next iteration, and in all future iterations, so `a` will never equal `b` and the pair is "infinite".

If the difference between `a` and `b` is even, then this will be true for all future iterations (by similar logic). To work on this case, let's work backwards from the final state. If the pair is finite, then the end of the iterative process will produce a pair `(k,k)`. The smaller integer in the prior iteration therefore was `k/2`, so the larger one was `3k/2`: `(k/2,3k/2)`. Continuing to follow the process backwards, the prior step then was `(k/4,k/4+3k/2)=(k/4,7k/4)`, preceded by `(k/8,k/8+7k/4)=(k/8,15k/8)`. If we abstract this pattern, we can see that any pair of the form `(m,(2^n-1)m)` (for any `n`) is finite.

This isn't a complete proof, but I believe that an even-differenced pair is finite if and only if one member of the pair is the product of the other and a value one less than a power of two. Please let me know if you can find a counter-example.

Here's the beginning of the brute-force process I used to come to that conclusion:

```
(1,1) <- impossible
(2,2) <- (3,1)
(3,3) <- impossible
(4,4) <- (6,2) <- (7,1)
(6,6) <- (9,3)
(8,8) <- (12,4) <- (14,2) <- (15,1)
(10,10) <- (15,5)
(12,12) <- (18,6) <- (21,3)
(14,14) <- (21,7)
(16,16) <- (24,8) <- (28,4) <- (30,2) <- (31,1)
           [*3]      [*7]      [*15]     [*31]
(18,18) <- (27,9)
(20,20) <- (30,10) <- (35,5)
```

Thanks, this was fun to work through.

Comment: @nivoli  a counter example for the case if (a-b) is even : (3,5) , trying the conditions [5-3 is even], [5 is not a multiple of 3 ] so it should be infinite ; but it is finite as shown in the example of the question, so i think that the condition you found is sufficient but not necessary , I'm thinking that the solution of a Diophantine equations will be a more generalization to this...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first half of the function, where a>b. If this remains iteration after iteration we have:
[image]

The "no-infinite" condition is a<sub>n</sub>=b<sub>n</sub> for some "n". So
[image]

The second half of the funtion is just a swap(a,b) when some a<sub>k</sub>< b<sub>k</sub>

```
a0 < b0(1+2k+1)
```

The problem becomes finding if a<sub>0</sub> is a multiple of b<sub>0</sub> with the factor (1+2<sup>k+1</sup>) for some 'k'.

This is another problem. You can discard any pair (a,b) when a=2<sup>k</sup>·b. You only have to test several k while a>2<sup>k</sup>·b

#### Note

I do not have checked all my maths. You may find errors. The general idea remains.

#### Note 2

@Nvioli found an error. The right factor is (2<sup>k+1</sup>-1)

Comment: You've got something wrong: let k=1; then b_0=a_0 * (1+2^[1+1])=a_0*(1+2^2)=a_0*(1+4)=a_0*5. (1,5) becomes (2,4) becomes (4,2) etc. and is infinite...